# Why does uploaded picture show on all sites except this one?

Tags: bug, profile-picture

My uploaded picture shows on all sites except Meta SE. I haven't set a different one here, it just shows the default picture. Seems to be a bug?

Comment: I get the same picture for you here and on MSO (regedit screenshot). Looks like caching on your end.

Comment: @Mat I just solved it! See my answer.

Comment: As far as I can tell there was no bug here. Almost all of your accounts still used your old profile picture before you copied it across the network just now. At some point you changed your Stack Overflow profile picture, but didn't copy the changes. Only the sites you joined *after* making that change had your new one because they copied the profile you had on Stack Overflow, while other older accounts continued using your old profile picture.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by editing my profile on a site where my picture was showing OK. In the dropdown, I deselected my uploaded picture, then reselected it, and on save I chose the option to send the update to all sites. It now shows here too.

So if it is a bug, that action seems to be effective as a workaround anyway.